# Redirect to category tree page after success

Tags: php, magento

I want to redirect administrator to category tree page after success using controller.How can i achieve this
this is my custom module controller method

```
public function createsamplesAction(){

 $this->_redirect('catalog_category');

}
```

but it's showing 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
$this->_redirect(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/catalog_category'));
```